# MonoDroid UI Library

Tags: xamarin.android

Is there any way to build .dll library with UI Components which will include all necessary resource files and will be linkable to other MonoDroid projects? (except using .jar file and creating JNIEv proxies for controls)

Comment: What is the purpose for this other than organization of resources?

Comment: I have several MonoDroid projects and i want to create contrib lib with most common user controls. And maybe share it on github for all MonoDroid users.

Comment: You could create the controls programmatically OR use fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

Comment: Problem is that i need to store resources in the library.In Java -  you can create Android project and export it as jar file with all resources, but MonoDroid Library project build includes only classes without resources.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this currently in Mono for Android. The only thing that does work is creating the UI from code. If you need inspiration, check out the Runner project on this Github repository: https://github.com/SpiritMachine/NUnitLite.MonoDroid

It contains a set of UI controls in a separate library written fully in code.

It's not ideal, but you can do it.